# How do simple statistics based on polygons?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, shapefile, statistics

I have a shapefile from a city. I divided this shapefile into polygons (squares, majority). I would like to perform simple statistics in each square in a easy way, because it is almost impossible to do it by hand.

Can someone help me? I have basic knowledge of scripting. I have ArcGIS 10.

---

1st edit:
 I have a shapefile of points. Each point is a well, each well have some informations (example: depth). I want to have statistics for each square. I want to know how many wells I have in each squares, what is the mean of the depth and so on

Comment: There are a lot of ways to produce statistics, you may want to specify the nature of the stats you are looking for, are you wanting stats on the group of polygons? on the attributes in the polygon data table? or do you have other point/line data you are summarizing based on which polygon they occupy?

Comment: "or do you have other point/line data you are summarizing based on which polygon they occupy?" --> This option!

I have a shapefile of points. Each point is a well, each well have some informations (exemple: depth). 

I want to have statistics by square. Then I want to know how many wells I have in each squares, what is the mean of the depth and so on.

Comment: You really need more detail in your post regarding type of statistics and on what (e.g., polygon attributes, raster). You should also be aware of the MAUP issue related to the way you created your data (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modifiable_areal_unit_problem).

Answer (score 3):

regarding your updated info in the comments, you could assign a unique id to each polygon in it's attribute table, and make a spatial join onto the well point file (right click on the well file in the TOC, go to joins and relates\join... ; select the option to join based on spatial location; select the polygon file as the join layer, and select the option to join data from the nearest feature [the one polygon the feature is within]). once you do that, you can go into the well file table, and summarize the polygon id field, which will give you a number of summary statistics you can generate for each well attribute.

Comment: Wow!
It worked!
Thank you very much! I was thinking that I would need to write some scripts but your solution is much more elegant!

Comment: If TDavis answered your question, go ahead and click the check mark to the left to mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you are meaning by simple statistics, but the summary statistics tool might be a good starting place.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001z000000